# Translating sentences in PygLatin

Tags: python

I was able to make a translator, but it only translates one word. I really don't understand how to make it possible to translate a sentence with multiple words.

Hope someone can help me!

```
#List Operators
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
consonants = ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

#Instructions
print ("Program to translate sentences to pig latin.")
print ("Avoid using symbols and punctuation.")

#Define word
word= ""
while word != "exit":
    word = input("Enter a word(s) to translate or Exit: ")
    words = word.split()
    for word in words:
        if word.isalpha():
            word = str(word)

#Translate word by checking how it starts
            first_letter = word[0]
            if len(word) == 1:
                print ("Word is only one letter!")
            else:
                if first_letter in vowels:
                    print (word + "yay")
                else:
                    second_letter = word[1]
                    if first_letter in consonants:
                        print (word[1:] + word[0] + "ay")
                    else:
                        print (word[2:] + word[:2] + "ay")

        else:
            if word.lower() == "exit":
                word = word.lower()
                print("Goodbye.")
            else:
                print("Invalid word: %s! Try again." % word)

    stored_strings = []
    stored_strings.append('word')
    ''.join(stored_strings)
    print("")
```

Comment: You should have a look at the split function, that splits a sentence with a delimiter.

Comment: Your code does not deal the case where one inputs only one character like `a`

Answer (score 0):

Accept the entire set of words as a sentence and then split on whitespace. Here is the documentation on the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function. Something like this will help you,

```
sentence = raw_input("Enter your sentence ")
words = sentence.split()
for word in words:
    # Execute your pyglatin code on `word`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply divide your sentence into an array of words with string.split() function, then iterate over all words.

For instance, adding two lines to your snippet would give you the desired result.

```
# List Operators
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
consonants = ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

# Instructions
print("Program to translate sentences to pig latin.")
print("Avoid using symbols and punctuation.")

# Define word
word = ""
while word != "exit":
    word = input("Enter a word(s) to translate or Exit: ")
    words = word.split()
    for word in words:
        if word.isalpha():
            word = str(word)

            # Translate word by checking how it starts
            first_letter = word[0]
            second_letter = word[1]
            if first_letter in vowels:
                print(word + "yay")
            else:
                if first_letter and second_letter in consonants:
                    print(word[2:] + word[:2] + "ay", end=" ")
                else:
                    print(word[1:] + word[0] + "ay", end=" ")

        else:
            if word.lower() == "exit":
                word = word.lower()
                print("Goodbye.")
            else:
                print("Invalid word: %s! Try again.\n" % word)
    print("")
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code to simplify it a little.

I have added a condition where one inputs only one letter. I have placed the exit condition at the beginning of the `while` loop.

I could not check what the algorithm really does since I have no specification.

```
# List Operators
vowels = "aeiou"
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"

# Instructions
print ("Program to translate sentences to pig latin.")
print ("Avoid using symbols and punctuation.")

# Infinite loop that will be stopped when user inputs `exit`
while True:
    words = input("Enter a word or a sentence to translate or Exit: ").lower()
    if words == "exit":
        print("Goodbye.")
        break
    for word in words.split():
        # Translate word by checking how it starts
        first_letter = word[0]
        if first_letter in vowels:
            print (word + "yay\n")
        elif len(first_letter) == 1:
            print (word + "\n")
        else:
            second_letter = word[1]
            if first_letter in consonants and second_letter in consonants:
                print (word[2:] + word[:2] + "ay\n")
            else:
                print (word[1:] + word[0] + "ay\n")
```

Comment: How would you re-join the output strings after the split function?

Comment: Well, you need to store all the strings that are printed with command `print` in a list for example. (`stored_strings=[]`, `stored_strings.append('word')`). Then you can use `''.join(stored_strings)` or `'\n'.join(stored_strings)`

Comment: I tried to append and join the strings but that had no result. Admittedly I am just a beginner. I updated my code so that you can see what I have so far. Thanks!

Comment: You need to replace ALL print instance `print(xyz)` with `stored_strings.append(xyz)`, then apply the join function (`print('\n'.join(stored_strings))`). Btw, you should up vote the answer, if you want to get helped.

Answer (score 0):

word = raw_input("Enter a word to translate or Exit: ")    Allows you to input continuously

But typing a letter in your code can cause an error

Need to do：

#

try:

```
        first_letter = word[0]

        second_letter = word[1]

        if first_letter in vowels:

            print (word + "yay\n")

        else:

            if first_letter and second_letter in consonants:

                print (word[2:] + word[:2] + "ay\n")

            else:

                print (word[1:] + word[0] + "ay\n")

    except IndexError:

       print('Input word len < 2 !')
```

Comment: You should clean up your answer.